# Node.js in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I am new to Node.js and I am using WebStorm as my IDE since I've used PhpStorm in my old php days and I've found it great.

What I noticed is that the autocomplete and suggested key words, functions, properties... in WebStorm in Node.js projects is far from being accurate or helpful while it was extremely helpful in PhpStorm making development really intuitive.

Is there  anyway to make WebStorm more helpful to Node.js developer?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-and-debugging-node-js.html

Comment: A bit off topic: If you still have PhpStorm (modern version) -- use it. "PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP + DB" basically.

Answer (score 0):

Webstorm is mainly for web with focus on Javascript, there are some plugins (from the settings menu) that you can install for node js.